# In This Excel VBA Could some body tells me Why it refuses to take after parameter in the add method in worksheets object?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is:

```
Sub Copy_Filtered_Table()
    Dim aSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    i = ActiveSheet.Index
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Copy
->  Set aSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=i)
    aSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

The workbook format is .xlsm Excel 2016
it has sheets after and before the active sheet

Also I Have tried doing it with out the aSheet variable like this

```
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add After:=i
```

It did not work too. both cases gives error 1004 Method 'Add' of object 'Sheet' faild.
If I ommited the After parameter it works but putting the result new sheet before the active sheet which exactly I am avoiding.

Comment: `After` expects sheet reference, not a sheet index

Comment: Yes as @paxdiablo taught me, I got that now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to insert relative to an existing sheet, you need to provide the actual *sheet* rather than its index, using one of:

```
Set aSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i))
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
```

Which one you choose depends on whether you immediately want to do something with the sheet without searching for it again but I suspect you already know that, given your question.

---

As an aside (though I haven't tried), I suspect getting the index of the current sheets then turning that back into the current sheet object is a bit unnecessary. You may want to just try:

```
Set aSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet)
```

Comment: Thank you, totally forgot that before and after take sheet object not index number
I will accept this answer after the waiting period gets over
can I ask u 1 more thing?
how to lose the dotted rectangle after the .copy method?

Comment: you are right about getting the index and feeding it back
Just tried it and it works as perfect as it should be and it makes more sense actually